# Which Hiawatha webserver build version is right for my Linode?

Tags: intel, xeon, web-server

From the [Hiawatha 8.1 blog entry comment](http://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/weblog/33):

> [...] the i686 [build] requires a Pentium 3 or newer CPU. If your processor supports the i686 build however, my quick & dirty benchmarks show a roughly 7% improvement in serving static content, and around a 25% improvement in PHP rendering time via FastCGI.

My Linode 1024:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5520  @ 2.27GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5520  @ 2.27GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5520  @ 2.27GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5520  @ 2.27GHz
```

I've tried looking up information on Intel processors at Wikipedia, but am not sure if I should use the i686 build or not.

Comment: What does `uname -a` show in the architecture field?

Comment: Ah... `i686`. I expect that means I can use the i686 build. :) Thanks.

Comment: The other main possibility would have been the x86-64 architecture.  There might be a Hiawatha build optimized for that.

Comment: Please note that you should probably use the relevant repo for whatever linux distro you're running.  Hiawatha apparently has packages available.  Your package manager will take care of the architecture issue, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's fair to assume that the L5520 (a fairly modern Xeon release) counts as a "Pentium 3 or newer CPU", and therefore you should use the i686 version rather than the generic i386 one.